# multiple record request on https://scra.dmdc.osd.mil/scra/#/home

Tags: excel, database, text, export-to-csv

essentially this program will let you enter the; last name, first name, social security and will comeback with a .pdf that states weather there active military or not. We save these and upload to respective accounts.

I am a amateur programmer looking for help.

I am attempting to do a multiple record SCRA search on: https://scra.dmdc.osd.mil/scra/#/home

Essentially this is a batch upload to do many searches at one time. The user guide asks for a .txt file and to format the file with fixed width columns. Reporting currently gives us an excel sheet with all the info, to possibly refrain from doing these daily one account at a time, is there a way to transfer and format excel data on to .txt formatted properly.

Not sure if I’m asking in the right place, I Apologize if I’m not!

Comment: Could you show a sample? What about the expected output?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/100433/export-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-fixed-width-text-file